# simplified Ternary expression

Tags: java, ternary

I am trying to wrap my head around a small block of code `int maximumVal = counter > 20 ? 20 : counter;`

I know that `?` is used for a `true` `if` expression and : is used for a `false` `if` expression

is this what that expression is saying in simplified `if else` terms?:

```
if (counter > 20) {
int maximumVal = 20;
else {
maximumVal = counter;
}
```

Comment: I would rewrite it `int maximumVal = Math.min(20, counter);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of it as

```
int maximumVal;
if (counter > 20) {
    maximumVal = 20;
} else { 
    maximumVal = counter;
}
```

maximumVal must be declared outside the if in order for it to be visible to code following this.

The conditional expression has the advantage where you can know the variable being assigned from the expression is assigned some value, where in the if-else form you have to read both branches to verify the variable gets set.

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operation operator(?)

Syntax:
variable = condition ? (if true)value1 : (if false)value2;

and yes its basically a if-else statement